# Fined Find common names across several years

Tags: r

I have data with two columns, the first column is years from 1980 :2020 and the second column contains characters or names within each year. I am interested in producing two columns` table with the number of times specific name was present in one column and the years that the name was replicated in, in another column.

Any idea how to do that?
Thank you in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like @ThomasIsCoding solution a lot, but here are solutions using `dplyr` and `data.table`.

Example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  year = sample(1990:1993, 10, replace=TRUE),
  name = sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE))
```

tidyverse & `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)


dat %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), years = toString(sort(unique(year))))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   name      n years     
#>   <chr> <int> <chr>     
#> 1 a         1 1993      
#> 2 b         2 1992, 1993
#> 3 c         2 1990      
#> 4 d         5 1992, 1993
```

`data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(dat)
dt[, .(.N, years=toString(sort(unique(year)))), by="name"]

#>    name N      years
#> 1:    b 2 1992, 1993
#> 2:    d 5 1992, 1993
#> 3:    c 2       1990
#> 4:    a 1       1993
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `aggregate` like below?

```
aggregate(year ~ ., df, toString)
```

such that

```
> aggregate(year ~ ., df, toString)
   name                         year
1     A             1983, 1990, 2012
2     B                   1984, 2007
3     C                         2014
4     D                         1981
5     E             2001, 2005, 2006
6     F                   2015, 2018
7     G                   1982, 1997
8     I                   1998, 2002
9     J 1993, 1996, 2008, 2016, 2017
10    K                         1986
11    L                         2010
12    N             1987, 1995, 2004
13    O             1999, 2011, 2019
14    R                         1988
15    S                         1989
16    T                   2013, 2020
17    U             1991, 1992, 2000
18    V                         1994
19    W                         1985
20    Y             1980, 2003, 2009
```

or `table`

```
> table(df)
      name
year   A B C D E F G I J K L N O R S T U V W Y
  1980 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  1981 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1982 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1983 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1984 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1985 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  1986 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1987 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1988 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1989 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  1990 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1991 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  1992 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  1993 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1994 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  1995 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1996 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1997 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1998 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1999 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  2001 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2002 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2003 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  2004 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2005 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2006 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2007 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2009 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  2010 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2011 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2012 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2013 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  2014 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2015 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2016 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2017 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2018 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2019 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2020 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  year = 1980:2020,
  name = sample(LETTERS, 41, replace = TRUE)
)
```